# How to convert character to numeric with pre-specified labels

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert character/factors in R that can convert that type of data to numeric to pre-specified labels.

For example, Males = 0, Females = 1.

I want to specifically label it that way not randomize. 
I tried `add_label` but it only adds labels but it does not convert data to numeric.
I also tried `replace()`, but I can't do with that either

Comment: `df$gender = ifelse(df$gender=="Males", 0, 1)` ?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble figuring out which direction you want to convert in.  Can you show an example input and output vector?

Comment: @R.Schifini Every value is converted to 1.

Comment: @BenBolker I want to convert Males, females -> 0,1.... With specific labels and to numeric values.

Comment: you can try `car::Recode` or `plyr::mapvalues`. They generally work well with factors

Comment: @RAB That worked perfectly! I later on used as.numeric(as.character(df)) and the values turned out to be precisely the same. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If want to go from {Males, Females} to {0,1}:

```
s <- c("Males","Females","Males","Females","Females")
labs <- c("Males","Females")
f <- factor(s, levels=labs)  ## specify order
as.numeric(f)-1  ## label numbers start at 1, so subtract 1
## result: [1] 0 1 0 1 1
```

If you want to be even more general

```
vals <- c(0,1)
vals[match(s,labs)]
## same result as above
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, but all values are converted to NA. I've tried all 3 of your approaches.

Comment: that's too bad.  Could you please post a [mcve] so we can see what's going on?

Comment: note that the values of your data must match the `levels`/`labs` specifications *exactly* (including case).

Comment: vals <- c(0,1)
df$gender <- vals[match(df$gender, vals)]

Comment: Yep, checked the labels and levels